# how to write in config file once during installation

Tags: c#, installation, app-config

I have some variables that I need to set once while installing. For example I need to set COM port, registration of the vehicle and so on...

How to write to config file during installation once and only read it always after. Is there any custom installation tool. I have looked at WinX and I must say that I was not so pleased.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a new form like SplashScreen and do u r initialisation in app.config, add a new variable named `fInstalled` in app.config and change its value to true.

Now where ever you start your application check whether `fInstalled` is true, if it is false go to your MainForm else reconfigure using splashscreen.

SplashScreen is just an example or u can also do without splash screen.

Comment: I don't understand it right. I don't know if I was clear enough. I want to be able to have a custom installation window. Where I will set all the variables that I need, write them once in the config file and after that use it everytime when program is running. If this is what I need then please give me some link as I don't understand it correctly.

Comment: @denonth I think Kishore means have a bool variable initially set to false, do the app.config modifications, then set it to true, then as long as it's true don't make any changes, Kishore am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Its recommended to use [NSIS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nsis/)

with it you can manipulate XML config file during installation.